# Board games: How to change the default font on the board?

Tags: fonts, chess

While compiling my notes for the Go games, the default font for the `go` package included in `texlive-games` doesn't show quite well if printed out, I wonder how could I change the default font for the numbers showing on the stones? Thanks a lot, and here is some example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{go}
\begin{document}
\gofontsize{20}
\pos{c}{4}=\black{3}
\pos{c}{7}=\black{17}
\pos{d}{3}=\black{13}
\pos{d}{5}=\black{15}
\pos{d}{8}=\black{21}
\pos{e}{4}=\white{12}
\pos{e}{7}=\white{14}
\pos{e}{9}=\white{20}
\pos{f}{6}=\white{16}
\pos{g}{4}=\black{19}
\[
\showdiagram a-g:1-9
\]
\end{document}
```

And sorry for putting on a [chess](/questions/tagged/chess) tag, couldn't find a proper [board-games](/questions/tagged/board-games) or [go](/questions/tagged/go) tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fonts in the `go` and the newer `igo`package are hard coded and the numbers on the stones are on the glyphs of the fonts and so can't be changed. It would be not very difficult to use another font with one of the package. But you would need an alternative first. The `go` package and the `igo` package use currently metafont (bitmap) fonts. A type 1 font would improve the look on screen considerably.

An alternative is the `psgo` package. With it adjusting the font is easy. It uses postscript so it needs latex + dvips. But it has only about 300 line of code and it shouldn't be very difficult to make a tikz-version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{psgo}

\begin{document}
\begin{psgoboard}[9]
\move*{c}{3}
\move*{g}{7}
\pass*
\move*{f}{1}
\move*{a}{9}
\move{f}{6} % new \move commands
\move{e}{6}
\pass
\move{c}{5}
\end{psgoboard}


\renewcommand{\golabelformat}[1]{{#1}}

\begin{psgoboard}[9]
\move*{c}{3}
\move*{g}{7}
\pass*
\move*{f}{1}
\move*{a}{9}
\move{f}{6} % new \move commands
\move{e}{6}
\pass
\move{c}{5}
\end{psgoboard}

\end{document}
```