# sgf2dg: Board color with White Stones

Tags: pdftex, color

I am using the software `sgf2dg` to create diagrams for the [game of Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)). The software is available here: http://search.cpan.org/~reid/Games-Go-Sgf2Dg-4.252/

I want to add a board color without messing up the White stones as in this example:

[image: Board with gray white stones]

The board color is alright, however I want the White stones to remain their white color and not take on the color of their background.

This was created with (MWE)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{gooemacs}
\input{sgf2dg.tex}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{gray!20}{
\vbox{\goo
\hbox{\0??<\0??(\0??(\0??(\0??(\- !(\0??(\0??(\0??>}
\hbox{\0??[\0??+\0??+\0??+\- @+\- !+\- @+\0??+\0??]}
\hbox{\0??[\0??+\0??*\0??+\0??+\- @+\0??*\0??+\0??]}
\hbox{\0??[\0??+\- @+\0??+\0??+\0??+\0??+\0??+\0??]}
\hbox{\0??[\- @+\- !+\0??+\0??*\0??+\- @+\0??+\0??]}
\hbox{\0??[\0??+\- @+\0??+\0??+\- @+\- !+\0??+\0??]}
\hbox{\0??[\0??+\0??*\0??+\0??+\- @+\- !*\- @+\0??]}
\hbox{\0??[\0??+\0??+\0??+\0??+\0??+\- @+\0??+\0??]}
\hbox{\0??,\0??)\0??)\0??)\0??)\0??)\0??)\0??)\0??.}
\smallskip
\break
}}
\end{document}
```

Since the diagram is typeset as a font, I guess my actual question boils down to: How complicated is is to change a font so that encircled regions like `O` have a different color from the background?

---

The process to create readable pdf is: `sgf` -> `tex` -> `pdf`, but I am willing to change something about that.

---

Edit: The answer to this question [Board games: How to change the default font on the board?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46193/board-games-how-to-change-the-default-font-on-the-board)
does not apply here as they use a different package (`igo` and `psgo`).